# Erro ao inicia Eclipse Luna, erro java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/stylesheets/StyleSheet

Tags: eclipse, ide

Ao inicia o Elipse Luna recém instalado apareceu o seguinte erro no arquivo `.log.` no `\workspace\.metadata\`.
Abaixo o log do erro:

> !SESSION 2018-04-24 11:50:44.298 -----------------------------------------------
>   eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
>   java.version=9.0.4
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>   BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
>   Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-04-24 11:51:09.286
>   !MESSAGE Application error
>   !STACK 1
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/stylesheets/StyleSheet
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getCSSSWTEngine(ThemeEngineManager.java:41)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getEngineForDisplay(ThemeEngineManager.java:30)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createThemeEngine(PartRenderingEngine.java:1428)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1281)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1036)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.stylesheets.StyleSheet cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.100.v20140424-2042
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 26 more

O que se dá o erro? E qual melhor forma de corrigi-lo?

Comment: Se criar um novo workspace nao resolver o problema?

Comment: @Articuno, infelizmente criei um novo workspace e o problema persistiu, continua o mesmo.